# Tool for searching & analyzing results from multiple search engines

Tags: windows, software-rec, search-engines

Are there any tools/programs which can simultaneously search multiple search engines and analyze the results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Copernic](http://www.copernic.com/)** is very popular ... and free for personal use.

> Copernic Agent makes every Web search
>   a super-search with this intelligent
>   tool, trusted by millions of users
>   worldwide.

If you want a web-based solution, try **[WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/)**

Comment: Copernic seems great, but the Basic (free) version does not include some important features like "Advanced management of search and results" and "Summarize and analyze search results" :/ But of course, thanks.

Comment: @Mehper C. Palavuzlar - well, you didn't ask for free in particular ... and that's the usual approach: for free you get basic functionality, with paid versions then come the bells 'n' whistles. that actually works both ways, you throw a few quid to a software developer, it's a great motivation to improve the product and keep up the good work. :)